# Regex to restrict several scenarios

Tags: html, regex, validation, text, input

I need an html input to have some restrictions:

- Do not allow spaces
- Do not allow same char to be consecutive more than 3 times
- Do not allow numbers, 0-9

**Note:** Must allow accented mostly chars (ç, á, ê, etc...)

For now I just implemented the last rule (no numbers allowed):

```
/^([^0-9]*)$/
```

If you can show me this implemented on an html input it would be great.

Comment: Edited @TimBiegeleisen, thanks

Comment: I think you would need lookarounds to do this, and I'm not sure if HTML input regex supports this.

Comment: *"Must allow special utf-8 chars (ç, á, ê, etc...)"* is too broad, see the unicode table and explain clearly what kind of characters are allowed or not.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte, you are right. Well what mean was accented chars mostly

Comment: @HulaHula: only latin characters ? are ASCII non-letter character allowed: ` ~ { # ] ...` (except whitespaces and digits)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-spaces and non-digits are pretty straightforward - `^[^\s0-9]+$`. The non-repeating condition may be implemented with a negative lookahead `^(?!.*(.)\1{3})`:

```
^(?!.*(.)\1{3})[^\s0-9]+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/E02Hrh/3

Note that along with non-Latin letters it will allow special characters (`?`, `!`, `@`, etc.) but these are not explicitly prohibited in the question.

Answer (score 0):

For the non-quadrupal-repeat it's like Dmitry said.
Easy to do via a negative lookahead. `(?!.*(.)\1{3})`

For the special utf characters you could add a unicode range

```
^(?!.*(.)\1{3})[a-zA-Z\u00c0-\u00ff]+$
```

Or add the range(s) you expect, for example from the [supplement block](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/images.htm)

```
^(?!.*(.)\1{3})[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+$
```

Example with html input and regex pattern validation

```html
<form action="javascript:console.log('ok')">
 letters: <input type="text" name="letters" 
pattern="^(?!.*(.)\1{3})[a-zA-ZÀ-ÿ]+$" title="Letters">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted for whatever reason. Thanks, now my reputation is rounded to a modulus 10 again.

Comment: For a better view of the unicode table, I suggest this useful site: http://utf8-chartable.de/